# Request class is not available in a Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on ASP.NET Core 2.1 and I want to use `Request` class in razor page to get current domain by the following code:

```
@Request.Url.Authority
```

But `Request` is not recognized in razor page. How can I access to `Request` class in razor page? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request` should be available in a Razor page. You might be trying to use `Request` is a partial view, where it's not present. Try accessing it from the `Context` property which contains the current `HttpContext`:

```
@Context.Request.Url.Authority
```